# Saving data frame summary as data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

I used `tapply` to generate summaries by factor for a `data.frame`.  E.g.,

```
s <- with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, cyl, summary))
```

I see that the class of s is an array. Is there a simple way to convert the `tapply` outputs to another `data.frame`?

Comment: `aggregate()` might be a better function choice than `tapply()` given your desired output.

Comment: @MrFlick, the aggregated column from `aggregate` would be a `matrix`. It would need a (somewhat clumsy) `do.call(data.frame, aggregate(...))` type of approach.

Comment: Thanks for testing @AnandaMahto. I was on a mobile device where I couldn't.

Answer (score 4):

The typical approach is to use `do.call(rbind, ...)`, like this:

```
do.call(rbind, s)
#   Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
# 4 21.4   22.80   26.0 26.66   30.40 33.9
# 6 17.8   18.65   19.7 19.74   21.00 21.4
# 8 10.4   14.40   15.2 15.10   16.25 19.2
```

As mentioned by @akrun in the comments earlier, wrapping it in `as.data.frame` would get you a `data.frame`.

---

If you are open to alternatives, you can also try "data.table", with which you can do:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, as.list(summary(mpg)), by = cyl]
#    cyl Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
# 1:   6 17.8   18.65   19.7 19.74   21.00 21.4
# 2:   4 21.4   22.80   26.0 26.66   30.40 33.9
# 3:   8 10.4   14.40   15.2 15.10   16.25 19.2
```